# using rename in linux force rename of folders and thus force merge them

Tags: linux, rename

using rename in linux force rename of folders and thus force merge them

I have folders like (random example) with files in them (that can be identical).

- b_001 c_001
- b_002 c_002
- b_003 c_003
- b_004 c_004
- (and ....etc)

using rename  `rename s/b_//' * and rename s/c_//' *`
fails cause directories not empty.

How can I force such rename and merging of multiple folders by using rename?

Comment: `by using rename` .. you can't. The merge process is essentially a combination of moving, renaming and deleting files.  There is a good article on it [here](https://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/how-to-merge-two-or-more-directories-in-linux/)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas so, there is no easy way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

perl-rename applies the regexp against the entire path that it was provided, not only against the filename, so what you could do is "rename" the *files*, not the folders, and this will move the files accordingly. (Move and rename are exactly the same operation behind the scenes.)

For example:

```
rename -v 's/b_//' b_*/*
rename -v 's/c_//' c_*/*
```

perl-rename should automatically create the folders as needed, but you could also pre-create them manually, or you could rename just the "b_" folders in the first round, then rename all "c_" and "d_" files next. So if the above did not work, this generally would:

```
rename -v 's/b_//' b_*
rename -v 's/c_//' c_*/*
```

Comment: I cant understand your proposition. I have directories to rename, eg. i have b_001 and  ab_001 with files on both folders. If rename ab_001 as b_001, must be merged with b_001, but that does not happen with rename. I think thunar can do it... but i want bash solution.